# Элемент Visibility.Hidden , но на скриншоте есть

Tags: c#, wpf

Перед тем как вызвать процедуру делающую скриншот, я скрываю фигуру `Visibility.Hidden`, на экране я её не вижу, открываю скриншот, а она там есть. Что происходит? Она не успевает скрыться или что?

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    figura.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    SdelatSkrinshot(x, y, width, height);
}
```

Comment: *Она не успевает скрыться или что?* – вполне возможно, пробуйте делать скриншот так: `Dispatcher.Invoke(() => SdelatSkrinshot(...));`

Comment: @АндрейNOP Именно так, ничего не меняется, правда я и не осознаю пока, что это за Dispatcher

Dispatcher.Invoke(() => SdelatSkrinshot(x, y, width, height));

Comment: Помогло вставить между моих строк await Task.Delay(100);

Comment: Дело в том, что элементы скрываются не сразу, а после цикла перерисовки. По идее, достаточно пропустить один цикл с DispatcherPriority.Render.

Comment: Спасибо, так всё отлично.
Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new Action(() => SdelatSkrinshot(x, y, width, height)));

Comment: @VladD, ответы писать вы пока не готовы? :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Пишу понемногу :)